# Generators of the Modular group (Motivation)

Tags: modular-forms, modular-function

I would like to know the motivation of the geometric argument applied on a 'fundamental domain' to get the generators of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. In particular, are there easier examples where this sort of proof works.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what argument you're talking about.

Comment: By Geometric argument, I mean the argument on the fundamental domain of upper half plane. For instance, in Serre's book A course in Arithmetic, I have seen that we use this fundamental domain to prove that S and T are the generators. I would like to see more examples of finding generators by looking at a 'subgroup' acting on a 'space'.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look at Serre's book *Trees*, which discusses arguments of this sort, and related theory.